# Generate the powerset as a list of 0/1 selection vectors

Tags: r

If e.g. |S| = 8, how can i get the 256 x 8 matrix with rows of the form:

```
> sample(c(0,1),8,replace=T)
[1] 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this helps:

```
library(e1071)
bincombinations(8)
```

Comment: Thank you. findFn('{Binary Combinations}') returns all the implemented functions to do that.

Comment: sounds good, but I don't find findFn() in base R. Is there a package for it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much faster (and arguably cleaner) version of `bincombinations`:

```
fast.bincombinations <- function(p)
    vapply(X = seq_len(p),
           FUN = function(i)rep(rep(0:1, each = 2^(p-i)), times = 2^(i-1)),
           FUN.VALUE = integer(2^(p)))

system.time(fast.bincombinations(24))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.967   1.056   3.995 

system.time(bincombinations(24))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  11.144  12.111  53.687
```

Let's also mention that `bincombinations` outputs a matrix of numerics, which is bad design IMHO.

Comment: nice, although speed up on my computer was "only" 3.5x. Nevertheless, significant improvement, cudos!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
s = 8                                        # <-- |s| = 8
pset <- t(sapply(0:(2^s-1),intToBits))[,1:s] # <-- a matrix of 256x8 raws
pset <- apply(pset ,2,as.integer)            # <-- raws to integers
```

Results:

```
> head(pset)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
> tail(pset)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[251,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    1
[252,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1
[253,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[254,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[255,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[256,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Here's another way:

```
s = 8;
res <- sapply(0:(s-1),function(x)rep(c(rep(0,2^x),rep(1,2^x)),2^(s-x-1)))
```

Comment: I used : expand.grid(lapply(1:s,function(x) c(0,1))) . I wonder, however, if there is a function for that.